# An algorithm to solve a square sum problem

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I found the following unsolved problem:

A 4x4-square of integers contains 30 subsquares A_i. Let B_i be the sum of integers (or elements) of A_i. What is the maximum number j such that for all positive k < j we have that k in ${B_1,...,B_{30}}$? And what is an example of such 4x4 square?

Comment: ARe there restrictions on the integers that are contained? eg do they have to be positive or non-negative or anything like that?

Comment: It does not matter if they are positive or negative or zero. Just integers.

Comment: I don't think j has been correctly explained. You state it must be greater than k, and also the maximum possible number that meets that criteria - surely that's just positive infinity.

Comment: If it is a positive infinity, how can you create 40 different integers such that they all belongs to set which have 30 integers?

Comment: @Gareth: no, it says for any positive k < j, k is the sum of a subsquare. Probably should say "all" k but the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start (and as an example), with A =

```
8  2  5  6
3  4  7  1
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I get j = 20

It gives a lower bound for j:

20 <= j <= 31

Answer (score 0):

A simple cardinality argument shows that j = 31 is an upper bound.

We can easily show that J = 30 is also an upper bound by noting that in the j = 31 case every sum must be a unique integer in the range [1,30].  Since every element in the 4x4 square is a unique integer > 0, the sum of the entire square is at least 120.  Since that isn't in the range [1,30], there are no squares where j = 31.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you will see that the integers are not necessary distinct and I don't see any reason why all of then must be positive.